# List comprehension out or range error or syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have two lists that I would like to combine with list comprehension, but keep getting an `IndexError: List index out of range` error:

```
List1 = [[u'Case1', u'DP1', u'Configuration1', u'New'], [u'Case2', u'DP2', u'Configuration2', u'New']]
List2 = [[u'DP1', u'EB1', u'Typ1'], [u'DP2', u'EB2', u'Type2'], [u'DP3', u'EB3', u'Type2']]


for key, item in enumerate(List2):
     List2[key] =  [item[0],[x for x in List1 if (x[1] == item[0] and x[2] == 'Configuration1')][0][3]]

print List2
```

I tried to add `else None` but then get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` exception:

```
List2[key] =  [item[0],[x for x in List1 if (x[1] == item[0] and x[2] == 'Configuration1') else None][0][3]]
```

My expected output would be:

```
[[u'DP1', u'New'], [u'DP2', None], [u'DP3',None]]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I edited your question to include both variants; I answered your initial question based on the index error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second list in `List1` has no value `'Configuration1'` at index 2, so the list comprehension is empty. Indexing an empty list gives an index error:

```
>>> List1 = [[u'Case1', u'DP1', u'Configuration1', u'New'], [u'Case2', u'DP2', u'Configuration2', u'New']]
>>> List2 = [[u'DP1', u'EB1', u'Typ1'], [u'DP2', u'EB2', u'Type2'], [u'DP3', u'EB3', u'Type2']]
>>> item = List2[1]
>>> [x for x in List1 if x[1] == item[0] and x[2] == 'Configuration1']
[]
>>> [x for x in List1 if x[1] == item[0] and x[2] == 'Configuration1'][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Your altered syntax is invalid; you cannot use `else` in a list comprehension `if` filter:

```
>>> [x for x in List1 if (x[1] == item[0] and x[2] == 'Configuration1') else None]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    [x for x in List1 if (x[1] == item[0] and x[2] == 'Configuration1') else None]
                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

That's because the `if` part is *not* a conditional expression but part of the list comprehension syntax. The `if` test *filters* the elements. You'd use a conditional expression in the left-hand side expression of a list comprehension, but doing so makes no sense here.

You should turn `List1` into a dictionary if you wanted to look up matching data:

```
configuration_data = {(entry[1], entry[2]): entry[3] for entry in List1}
```

This maps the items at indexes 1 and 2 to the element at index 3, so you can then simply use dictionary lookups to fill in your new list objects for `List2`:

```
List2 = [[item[0], configuration_data.get((item[0], 'Configuration1'), None)]
         for item in List2]
```

This list comprehension achieves the same effect as what you tried to do with your `for` loop with enumerate; produce a new list with matching configuration data:

```
>>> List1 = [[u'Case1', u'DP1', u'Configuration1', u'New'], [u'Case2', u'DP2', u'Configuration2', u'New']]
>>> List2 = [[u'DP1', u'EB1', u'Typ1'], [u'DP2', u'EB2', u'Type2'], [u'DP3', u'EB3', u'Type2']]
>>> configuration_data = {(entry[1], entry[2]): entry[3] for entry in List1}
>>> [[item[0], configuration_data.get((item[0], 'Configuration1'), None)] for item in List2]
[[u'DP1', u'New'], [u'DP2', None], [u'DP3', None]]
```

Comment: You're correct. Forgot my else, clause. Modified OP.

Comment: @user2242044 you cannot use `else` there, that's a syntax error. You are *filtering* the list comprehension.

Comment: Makes sense, but came here looking for help

Comment: @user2242044: sure, but I had to figure out what you were trying to achieve first.

Answer (score 0):

The if syntax for list comprehensions doesn't allows an "else".
This list comprehension generates the output you expect:

```
[item[0],[x if (x[1] == item[0] and x[2] == 'Configuration1') else [None] * 4 for x in List1][0][3]]
```

I just swapped the if..else to the front of the list comprehension and changed the `None` for a list so when you index it with `[3]` it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @user2242044 It's there because after the list comprehension you take the 4-th element with `[3]`... so all objects in the list comprehension should be indexable and have a 4th element.